# Does Firebase have native functionality for web-based authentication for desktop apps?

Tags: c++, firebase, qt, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a Qt app that I would like to authenticate through a webpage. The rough idea I have goes as follows.

1. I click a "Login" button on my Qt C++ app, which (using TLS) establishes a connection with the authentication server (perhaps with a POST request to an endpoint of my Firebase site), which sends back a one-time sign-in token.
2. The Qt app then opens the web browser and navigates the user to an authentication URL, with the sign-in token from step 1 encoded in the URL as a GET request.
3. User performs sign in on this webpage.
4. Once sign in is successful, Firebase cloud functions sends back a user ID token directly to my Qt desktop app (based on the sign-in token generated in step 1), which I can then use to access Cloud Firestore from my Qt app.

The idea is to use Firebase Cloud Functions to do all the back end stuff involved in this process.

I know I can directly use the Firebase authentication SDK for this to cut out the web browser altogether and just do authentication from inside my Qt app, but I'd like to use a webpage for extensibility reasons (E.g. if I wanted to add other sign-in methods in the future, I'd only have to update the sign-in website, rather than the Qt app). Also if user is already signed in on the site, they wouldn't need to sign into the app again.

Is this possible? Does Firebase have any native functionality to make something like this work? Would Firebase Cloud Functions even work for this sort of functionality?